# Using JQM (jQuery Mobile), why does the Collapsible nest another collapsible-heading-toggle intermittently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

The especially strange part about this is that I am not using JS to tweak anything, just the HTML data- attributes. Original Markup:

```
<div id="navContainer">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b">
        <h4>Go to a different page &raquo;</h4>
        <ul data-role="listview">

            <li class="current">
                <a href="http://m.brooksransom.com/about-us/" class="ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-carat-r ui-btn-active">About Us</a>
            </li>

          ...

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I should note that this is built on top of SilverStripe, a PHP MVC product. It makes heavy use if caching for performance, and sometimes clearing out the cache can fix a weird problem like this. Not seeming to in this case, but I wanted to "put all my cards on the table". Here is the JQM "Enhanced Markup":

```
<div id="navContainer">
    <div class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-theme="b" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="right" data-role="collapsible">
        <h4 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
            <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-b" href="#">
                <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-b" href="#">
                    Go to a different page »
                    <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
                </a>
                <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice the extra ui-collapsible-heading-toggle:

```
<a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-b" href="#">
    <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-b" href="#">
```

**Where is that coming from?** And why is it intermittent? Sometimes the page will start to load with it, and then it disappears and the markup ends up as it should. Sometimes it stays there permanently, and the events get all screwed up and the hidden content won't expand. There is nothing strange in the original markup that should be causing it. I'm baffled.

Here is the same exact page - I just refreshed it. Notice now that the markup and behavior is perfect. The content is a listview btw, same as in the original markup.

```
<div id="navContainer">
    <div class="ui-collapsible ui-collapsible-inset ui-corner-all ui-collapsible-themed-content ui-collapsible-collapsed" data-theme="b" data-collapsed="true" data-iconpos="right" data-role="collapsible">
        <h4 class="ui-collapsible-heading ui-collapsible-heading-collapsed">
            <a class="ui-collapsible-heading-toggle ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-right ui-btn-b" href="#">
                Go to a different page »
                <span class="ui-collapsible-heading-status"> click to expand contents</span>
            </a>
        </h4>
        <div class="ui-collapsible-content ui-body-inherit ui-collapsible-content-collapsed" aria-hidden="true">
    </div>
</div>
```

............

You can check it all live at http://m.brooksransom.com if you'd like. Any of the top links will "sometimes" exhibit this behavior. Sometimes if fixes it's rendering error a half-second later. Very strange.

Comment: Well, it's not about the markup. Check your scripts adding section, maybe you're adding jquery-ui.js multiple times? Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s644srys/) with your code, working nicely.

Comment: One workaround might be to use pre-rendered markup. See bottom of this page: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.3/collapsible/

Comment: I'm checking both out now. Either sound very plausible. I should also add that you can see the real thing @ http://m.brooksransom.com/portfolio/ or any of the top level links. Or course it looks weird on large displays, it only navigates there automatically for small ones. Nice testing route for me though. I do like my Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

@ezanker it looks like your solution has done it. There was one intermittent, but small, issue left where I had some hanging, but I remembered under the previous static navigation I was using data-ajax="false". As far jquery-mobile being added twice (I assume that's what Ilya Luzyanin meant) that wasn't it, I'm using an overall mobile solution that is part of the SilverStripe MVC framework. Let me know if there's anything else I'm doing incorrectly to give @ezanker full credit on this.